# How Can I Add An Existing Wpf Project To A Windows Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to add an existing WPF project to a windows project.

Comment: you mean project reference?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add to the Windows Project.

Read here. [Walkthrough: Manually Adding a Windows Presentation Foundation Element to a Windows Forms Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742881%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)